# List available AWS RDS instance type with go SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, amazon-rds, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to list all the available instance types that I can spawn for a given db engine (postgres/mysql). This at the moment is possible using the `aws` cli with the following command:

```
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine mysql
```

more options can be seen on this docs page - [describe-orderable-db-instance-options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-orderable-db-instance-options.html#examples)

However when I try to achieve the same with the aws go-sdk I can't find any similar function that can give me the list of available instances. Docs can be referred here - https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/rds

I am **NOT** interested in trying to list the provisioned instance and examine their instance types. Instead this is supposed to be a pre-provisioning step that allows me to choose available instance types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

[`func (*RDS) DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions(input *DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptionsInput) (*DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptionsOutput, error)`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/rds#RDS.DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions)

> Returns a list of orderable DB instance options for the specified DB engine, DB engine version, and DB instance class.

Usage:

```
input := &rds.DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptionsInput{
        Engine:          aws.String("mysql"),
        EngineVersion:   aws.String("5.6.27"),
        LicenseModel:    aws.String("general-public-license"),
        Vpc:             aws.Bool(true),
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that none of those parameters is required... I am going to edit to remove `DBInstanceClass` filter because that's what the OP is trying to enumerate.   https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/rds#DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptionsInput